# Linking to a specific place on external website

Tags: css, html

Is it possible to create a link on my website that then goes to a specific spot on another website. Sort of like an anchor tag but I'm not creating the other end of the anchor. Something tells me no but maybe there is a creative way to do this.

Comment: Nope. Need an anchor.

Answer (score 2):

If you view the source code (you could use F12 on your keyboard for most browsers) and you find an ID, then the answer is Yes.

Example:
You find `<h3 id="your-favorite-h3"></h3>`, just add `#your-favorite-h3` in the end of the URL. `www.example.com/page`**#your-favorite-h3**.

The complete code would be `<a href="http://www.example.com/page#your-favorite-h3">Click here</a>`